# Are the increments of a stochastic process driven by fractional Brownian motion independent?

Tags: stochastic-processes

I'm studying the following equation in the context of population dynamics
$$\tag1
    dX_t = \mu X_t dt + \sigma X_t dB^H_t
$$
where $B^H$ is the fractional Brownian motion (fBm) of Hurst parameter $H\in(0,1)$, that is a continuous Gaussian process starting at zero, with $B^H_t \sim \mathcal N(0,t^{2H})$ and with covariance $\mathbb E[B^H_t B^H_s] = \frac12(|t|^{2H}+|s|^{2H}-|t-s|^{2H})$.

According to the value of $H$

- if $H = 1/2$ then $B^H$ is the classical Brownian motion
- if $H < 1/2$ then increments of $B^H$ are negatively correlated
- if $H > 1/2$ then increments of $B^H$ are positively correlated

Moreover, the increment process $B^H_{t+1}-B^H_{t}$ is called fractional Gaussian noise (fGn) and has covariance $\gamma(k) = \frac12(|k-1|^{2H}-2|k|^{2H}+|k+1|^{2H})$.

---

To run numerical simulations, we first have to find estimators for the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

In this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4581546) the researches derive the maximum likelihood function in this way.

Let $f,g$ be two functions of $X_t$ and of $\theta$, vector of unknown parameters. Consider
$$\tag2
    dX_t = f(X_t,\theta) dt + g(X_t,\theta) dB^H_t
$$
the first and second moments of the increments of $X$ are given by
$$
   \mathbb E[dX|X,t] = f(X_t,\theta) dt
$$
$$
   \mathbb E[(dX)^2|X,t] = g^2(X_t,\theta) (dt)^{2H}.
$$

Partitioning $[0,T]$ as $0 = t_0 < t_1 < ... < t_N = T$ s.t. $\Delta t = t_{i+1}-t_i = T/N$, the SDE $(2)$ can be approximated by Euler-Maruyama method as
$$\tag3
    X_0 = x_0,\quad X_{n+1} = X_n + f(X_n,\theta)\Delta t + g(X_n,\theta)\Delta B^H_n 
$$
where $\Delta B^H_n = B^H_{t_{n+1}}-B^H_{t_n}$ (in the mentioned paper, $\Delta B^H_n$ is not explicitly defined, but I guess that the definition is the one that I wrote here) is the fGn and $0 \le n \le N-1$.

The probability density function of $(X_{n+1}, t_{n+1})$ starting at $(X_n,t_n)$ is then
$$\tag4
    \color{red}{p_X} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi g^2(X_n,\theta)(\Delta t)^{2H}}} \exp\Bigg(-\frac{(X_{n+1}-X_n-f(X_n,\theta)\Delta t)^2}{2g^2(X_n,\theta)(\Delta t)^{2H}}\Bigg)
$$
and the joint density gives the likelihood function $\mathcal L$, whose maximizers are the estimates of the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

For the initial sde $(1)$ we have $f(X_t,\theta) = \mu X_t$ and $g(X_t,\theta) = \sigma X_t$, hence
$$\tag5
    \color{red}{\mathcal L(\mu,\sigma) = \prod_{n=0}^{N-1}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2X^2_n(\Delta t)^{2H}}} \exp\Bigg(-\frac{(X_{n+1}-X_n-\mu X_n\Delta t)^2}{2\sigma^2X^2_n(\Delta t)^{2H}}\Bigg)
$$

---

The first question is related to the first $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ term: is the formula $(4)$ for the pdf of the increments of the process $X$, defined by $(3)$, correct?

The second question is related to the second $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ term: is the formula $(5)$ for the joint density (likelihood function) of the increments of the process $X$, defined by $(3)$, correct?

About the second question, my doubt is that since the increments of the fBm are not independent, maybe also the increments of the process $X$, defined by $(3)$, driven by the fBm are not independent. If this was the case, then we could not write the joint density of the increments of $X$ as the product of the individual densities. How to prove if the increments of $X$ are independent or not?

Comment: Intuitively, just from the SDE (1): take $s < t$ close together.  If $X_s$ is large for some $s$, then its drift and diffusion terms are both large, and we would expect $X_t - X_s$ to be larger in this case than if $X_s$ were small.  So it seems to me that $X$ certainly cannot have independent increments, not even in the $H=1/2$ case where the driving noise is standard Brownian motion.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't understand why the fact that the increment is larger in that case than if $X_s$ were small should imply that $X$ cannot have independent increments?

Comment: The intuition suggests that, for instance, $$P(|X_t-X_s| > 1 \mid 0 \le X_s \le 0.001) \ll P(|X_t - X_s| > 1 \mid 100 \le X_s \le 200).$$  If the process had independent increments then these two conditional probabilities would be equal.  "Independent increments" would mean that the value of $X_t - X_s$ is not influenced by $X_s$, and the SDE suggests just the opposite.

Comment: Thank you for further explanation. By definition a process $X$ has indep. increments iff the r.v. $(X_{t_1}-X_{t_0}), ...,(X_{t_n}-X_{t_{n-1}})$ are mutually independents. Is this equivalent to saying that $X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}$ is not influenced by $X_{t_{i-1}}$?

Comment: Not equivalent, but what I'm describing would be a consequence of independent increments.  Take $n=2$, $t_0=0$, $t_1=s$, $t_2=t$.  I am thinking of $X_0=0$ but it really makes no difference.

Comment: I see, thank you. So to correctly estimate the parameters do we have to follow the more difficult method explained here? (section 3) https://advancesindifferenceequations.springeropen.com/track/pdf/10.1186/s13662-018-1611-1

Comment: I'm not familiar with parameter estimation methods, sorry.  Maybe someone else can answer that.